# Scrape url of css file imports in css file and then remove them, in Python

Tags: python, css, url, import, minify

I need to grab all css imports(urls) within a css file. the example is:

```
@import url("/pub-assets/css/index/tac-holidaysale.css");
@import url("/pub-assets/css/index/tc1200-fonts.css");
@import url("/pub-assets/css/index/ad-banner.css");
```

so I need to get a list that includes:

```
/pub-assets/css/index/tac-holidaysale.css
/pub-assets/css/index/tc1200-fonts.css
/pub-assets/css/index/ad-banner.css
```

I need this for minifying the Css. After I grabbed all the urls, I need to remove all these imports. How can I do this in Python only?

Comment: It's not appropriate to ask people at this site to write code for you.  However, you might want to look at the Pythong string spit() method.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is making some assumptions, but you can split on the quote, and then only get the items between the quotes.

So your code would look something like this:

```
rules = []
with open("test.css") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("@import"):
            url = line.split('"')[1] # split on quote mark and get middle item
            rules.append(url)
```

This assumes that the line starts with @import, and that there is only one pair of quotes in the string. Let me know if these assumptions are too far reaching.

To remove the URL, you can do line.replace(url,''), or add the 0th and 2nd item of line.split('"')

Comment: Thanks for your answer. this is very good but I need the relative url not the whole import code

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just wrote a new solution not using regex.

Comment: Thanks very much. you made my day!

Comment: @Arya: this is very good, but the question was a flat-out demand for free work, together with language requirements and urgent begging. It's worth noting that some members of the community would rather these sorts of questions were not answered, so that Stack Overflow does not get a reputation as a sorting-house for free labour (or, at least, any more of a reputation than it already has).